# Zigzag Layout in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a webpage and trying to responsive a layout which is developed like this image

[image]

i'm using latest bootstrap for this and my code is

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/management-team/female.png" alt="" class="omt_img" />
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <h3 class="omt_title">Managing Director</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
        <h2 class="omt_name">Miss B Ayub</h2>
        <h4 class="omt_edu">PhD Psychology</h4>
        <hr>
        <p class="omt_para">Being a student of human behaviour, I observed that technology has greatly influenced our lives especially in the field of education. Students now a days are more engaged through technology based learning than traditional. This observation especially through my research inspired me to come up with OTI. This unique project is the solution to the problems faced by students of this day and age. Students want cutting edge technology with a tutor who is a facilitator and a mentor. This is exactly what OTI provides, online tutoring from the comfort of your own home and with the tutor of your choice.</p>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
        <h2 class="omt_name">Miss B Ayub</h2>
        <h4 class="omt_edu">PhD Psychology</h4>
        <hr>
        <p class="omt_para">Being a student of human behaviour, I observed that technology has greatly influenced our lives especially in the field of education. Students now a days are more engaged through technology based learning than traditional. This observation especially through my research inspired me to come up with OTI. This unique project is the solution to the problems faced by students of this day and age. Students want cutting edge technology with a tutor who is a facilitator and a mentor. This is exactly what OTI provides, online tutoring from the comfort of your own home and with the tutor of your choice.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/management-team/male.jpg" alt="" class="omt_img" />
        <h3 class="omt_title">Managing Director</h3>
    </div>
```

code is working fine for the tablet screen but when I moved to mobile devices the layout not showing perfect...and I'm getting layout like this

1. picture
2. designation
3. name
4. education
5. intro
6. name
7. education
8. intro
9. picture
10. designation

but i want to show things like this pattern

1. picture
2. designation
3. name
4. education
5. intro
6. picture
7. designation
8. name
9. education
10. intro

is it possible to do it with pure css using bootstrap?

Comment: the sm class will stack when the screen size gets small enough, have you tried xs instead, that will not resize even on small devices?

Comment: xs is working but the problem is the pattern of things aligned... just see the list i mentioned in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column ordering

Easily change the order of bootstrap CSS you Can Use `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*`

```
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/management-team/female.png" alt="" class="omt_img" />
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <h3 class="omt_title">Managing Director</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
    <h2 class="omt_name">Miss B Ayub</h2>
    <h4 class="omt_edu">PhD Psychology</h4>
    <hr>
    <p class="omt_para">Being a student of human behaviour, I observed that technology has greatly influenced our lives especially in the field of education. Students now a days are more engaged through technology based learning than traditional. This observation especially through my research inspired me to come up with OTI. This unique project is the solution to the problems faced by students of this day and age. Students want cutting edge technology with a tutor who is a facilitator and a mentor. This is exactly what OTI provides, online tutoring from the comfort of your own home and with the tutor of your choice.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/management-team/male.jpg" alt="" class="omt_img" />
    <h3 class="omt_title">Managing Director</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-md-pull-3 ">
    <h2 class="omt_name">Miss B Ayub</h2>
    <h4 class="omt_edu">PhD Psychology</h4>
    <hr>
    <p class="omt_para">Being a student of human behaviour, I observed that technology has greatly influenced our lives especially in the field of education. Students now a days are more engaged through technology based learning than traditional. This observation especially through my research inspired me to come up with OTI. This unique project is the solution to the problems faced by students of this day and age. Students want cutting edge technology with a tutor who is a facilitator and a mentor. This is exactly what OTI provides, online tutoring from the comfort of your own home and with the tutor of your choice.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: is `col-md-push` will work on mobile? or i have to use `col-xs-push`